# Why can't videos / streams run but youtube can?

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Trial Version here runing from 4 GB stick. I can watch/listen youtube but can't watch others videos and for example twitch streams - "No supported video backend available; Flash is not installed". My question why is that?

Answer (score 4):

Well, [YouTube has dropped flash](http://www.theverge.com/2015/1/27/7926001/youtube-drops-flash-for-html5-video-default) in favour of [HTML 5 video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video), by default, but others are still relying on flash, to install flash and other media codecs that you might not have installed, you need to install a package called `Ubuntu Restricted extras`

Open up your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and paste following command

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

if you don't need or have already installed other media codecs, paste the command below (instead of the one above)

```
sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: flashplugin appears to be only *recommended* by the restricted-extras package, not a *depends on*, so if you don't automatically install recommends you won't get it too

Comment: @Xen2050 now I think its somewhat complete answer to the question, feel free to edit though

Comment: Probably good enough as a comment, I read the default in most *ubuntu's is to install recommends, other distro's maybe not though (ex. mint at least in the past)

Comment: @Xen2050 I should probably learn the proper ways to handling questions like this from Meta site

Answer (score 1):

Flash player isn't available on the Trial version, because that would require installing the flashplayer plugin. It does not ship with the system by default is what I am trying to say.

Comment: Yeah but why does youtube runs / runs  ? HTML 5 ? Firefox can read that ? not understanding.

Comment: That's exactly right. The system can view HTML5 video from live media (USB in your case), but not adobe flashplayer as that program is considered "obsolete" at this point basically, so Ubuntu does not include it.

Comment: it runs **HTML 5 Video**  and it's supported on most of the modern browsers (excluding Safari and Microsoft Edge for some reason)